# How to disable auto-sort for AdvancedDataGrid

Tags: apache-flex, sorting, advanceddatagrid

I am using Flex 4, ActionScript 3.

I want to disable auto-sort. Meaning I want the sort to be executed only when the user clicks the column header, not when new rows are added to the binded collection or when values are changed.

So far, I've found only this on the Internet:
http://tomek.me/disable-sort-on-datagrid-edit-update/
I'd like to avoid doing that if possible.

Many months ago, I found a solution that involved using event.preventDefault() placed somewhere. I thought I wouldn't have a problem finding it again, but I am.

Can someone please help? Thanks!
Bon :-D

Edit/Delete Message

Answer (score 0):

I have face that problem many times before and get the same result as you get is NULL.

It in not possible at all and if possible please change in mx:internal otherwise there is no solution for that.

Have a nice day..